# Dynamics CRM plugin parent context

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm

I have a requirement to prevent the closing of an appointment from the Contact form (in the list of activities). 
How can I detect that the appointment was closed from the Contact form? 
I tried with `context.ParentContext.PrimaryEntityName`, but it is "appointment" even in this case! 
The plugin is postoperation synchronous.

Comment: This is a bad design. Why would a user have permission to close an appointment __BUT__ not be allowed to close it from a particular view, that doesn't make sense. I'm curious what this would accomplish. As Arun has stated in his answer, the plugin has no knowledge of where on the UI the request originated (or even if it was from the UI versus SDK call.)

Answer (score 1):

Plugin does not know from where action is initiated. In your case, you want to identify if the Close appointment action is taken by User - navigate from Contact form.

Better to remove the navigation - Activities from Contact or filter out the Appointments in Contacts - Activities Associated view. If needed, may be a new view can be created & set it as default.